# React redux is not updating the ui while delete action being dispatched

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a list of element in my component there every list have an delete button. Although delete is working perfectly fine but the problem is it is not updating the ui To update the ui i need to refresh my page to update it.

I tried to finding the issue but unable to find it.

These are my code.

> actions

```
export const deleteCartItem = (cartId) => (dispatch) => {
  new _rest()
    .delete(`order/cart?cartIds=${cartId}`)
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch({
        type: actionTypes.DELETE_CART_ITEM,
        payload: response.data.status,
        cartId: cartId,
      });
      dispatch(getItemsAddedToCart());   <--- here getItemAddedtoCart action my @get request to server to get all the item in cart.
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({
        type: actionTypes.DELETE_CART_ITEM_ERROR,
        error: err,
      });
    });
};
```

> reducers.js

```
    const initialState = {
      isFetching: false,
     fetched: false
      teamWithZero: null,

    };

    export default (state = initialState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.GET_CART_LOAD:
          return {
            ...state,
            isFetching: true,
          };
        case actionTypes.GET_CART_SUCCESS:

          const teamWithZero = action.payload._embedded.cartResourceList.filter(
            (item) => {
              return item.teamWith === 0 && item.priceType === "TEAM";
            }
          );


          console.log("teamzero-3", teamWithZero);
          return {
            ...state,
            teamWithZero: teamWithZero,

            fetched: true,
            isFetching: false,
          };
case actionTypes.DELETE_CART_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        cartList: state.cartList.filter(
          (item) => item.cartId !== action.cartId
        ),
        status: action.payload,
      };
    case actionTypes.DELETE_CART_ITEM_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.error,
      };
```

> CartContainer.js

```
if (isFetching) {
  return <p>Loading...</p>;
} else if (fetched) {
  return (
    <Grid contaner lg={12}>
      <Cart 
        deleteCartItem={deleteCartItem}
        teamWithZero={teamWithZero}
      />
    </Grid>
  );
```

> CartContainer.jsx

```
<Grid contaner lg={12}>
          <Cart
            teamWithZero={teamWithZero}
          />
        </Grid>
```

> Cart.jsx

```
{teamWithZero && teamWithZero.length > 0 && (
              <WaitingCartItem waitingItem={teamWithZero} teamBanner={true} />
            )}
```

> WaitingCartItem.jsx

```
const WaitingCartItem = ({
  waitingItem,
  handleCheckBoxChange,
  withTeam,
  teamBanner,
}) => {
  const [waitingData, setWaitingData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setWaitingData(waitingItem);
  }, [waitingItem]);

  return waitingData.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <Grid
        key={item.productId}

        container
        className="margin15"
      >
        <Grid
           className="cart"
        >
          <Grid container justify="flex-end" item xs={1}>
            <Checkbox
              onChange={handleCheckBoxChange}
              style={{ padding: "0px" }}
            />
          </Grid>

        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: so where is DELETE_CARD_ITEM execution in reducer?

Comment: @DmitryReutov i have updated the code have a look

Comment: did you check in debugger that DELETE_CART_ITEM comes to reducer and updating state? And show the component code, at least concerning props and useEffect hook

Comment: I checked `getItemsAddedToCart()` request and when i make delete request It does give response null that is fine as it is getting data from database. But when i checked the `Cart`  component which is a class component. It still shows the data but when i refresh only the it gets disappear.

Comment: @adityakumar In redux devtools you can see the difference in state after DELETE_CART_ITEM was dispatched. If the card has not been removed from state then maybe `item.cartId !== action.cartId` always return false (comparing string with number?)

Comment: @HMR All the items get removed pretty well and ui do get updated only the last item which is left after deleting all other item has this issue i don't know why although i  cunverted `parseInt(item.cartId) !== parseInt(action.cartId)` still it has the same problem.

Comment: @adityakumar  How are you rendering each item in the list? Are you using index as unique key for each item?

Comment: yes i am using `index ` for key.

Comment: @HMR even if i change it to something else it still has same issue.

Comment: @adityakumar How are you rendering each item in the list, can you provide the code?

Comment: @HMR I have updated code have a look.